# "net::ERR_ABORTED 404" error in a NodeJS app running on Nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, ejs

I have an SPA facing this error and I cannot seem to figure out why I am receiving it.

Bellow, my server.js

```
// Load Node modules
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var falaUser = require("./routes/falaUser");

//Config files
process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR'] = __dirname + '/config/';
console.log("Usando "+process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR'] +" como diretório de configurações");
var config = require("config");

// Initialise Express
var app = express();

// Render static files
app.use(express.static('./public/'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/falauser", falaUser);

// Set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var server = app.listen(config.get("port"), config.get("hostname"), function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Rodando bacana em https://' + host + ':' + port)
});

// Root Route
app.get('/strapiClient', function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});
```

Here, relevant part of nginx.conf

```
upstream strapiClient {
    server botboutique.com.br:3847;
}
```

Here, relevant part of nginx/sites-enabled/00-default.ssl.conf

```
    # strapiClient
    location /strapiClient  {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.ejs;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_pass http://strapiClient;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

Here, my HTML header partials in my ..views/partials/hearders.conf

```
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BOTIKE - Robôsitos que conversam com pessoas e negócios</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/cropped-favicon_botike-192x192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500;900&display=swap">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700;900&display=swap">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css">

    <!-- Animação dos balões da capa -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation-icoHum.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation-icoBot.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation-lettering.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css">

    <!-- Script principal -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripto.js"></script>
</header>
```

My scripts.ejs in ..views/partials/partials:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js "></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js "></script>
```

That´s my files structure:

[image]

The rendered page can acessed at [botboutique.com.br/strapiClient](https://botboutique.com.br/strapiClient)

A weird thing: while Edge and Firefox shows in the console the expected URL (botboutique.com.br/strapiClient/some-directory/some-file), Goolge Chrome supress "strapiCLient" from the URL).

**A final thing:** I'm facing a `"Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."` but I think that I must to correct 404 error first before going into this...

My /etc/nginx/conf-available:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection '1; mode=block';
add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";
add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin;
```

Comment: use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'/));` instead of `app.use(express.static('./public/'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ivan Shatsky pointed, be sure about browser context: that's prety important to understand how relative links will be served. In my scenario, I put an extra slash at the end of `location /strapiClient/` and it makes everything work. So, `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/00-default.ssl.conf` was the only file that I edit to resolve the context and find the files correctly.

Unfortunatelly and for some reason that I didn't understand (yet) NodeJS refused to serve the pages using `express.static` at `server.js`. And the solution that worked for me is quite verbose and seems like a "brute force" approach:

```
app.use('*/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/images')));
app.use('*/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/js')));
app.use('*/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/css')));
app.use('*/slick-1.8.1', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/slick-1.8.1')));
```

Despite [I'm still struggling with how NodeJS is serving the pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589423/unexplainable-node-js-cannot-post-get-errors), this question is solved. Thanks again @Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

When you serve a web app rather than some kind of API endpoint under an URI prefix, generally you should choose

```
location /prefix/ {
    ...
}
```

rather than

```
location /prefix {
    ...
}
```

You may think there should no significant difference in those two; however, the difference is more than significant - the opened page will have different [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) in those two cases. When you open your page using `/strapiClient` URI, your browsing context is `/` and when you open your page using `/strapiClient/` URI, your browsing context is `/strapiClient/`. And it is the browsing context that determines how relative links will be processed - would be the script from the `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripto.js">` tag requested as `/js/scripto.js` or as `/strapiClient/js/scripto.js`. I cannot check Edge or Firefox right now; however, using Google Chrome your assets are being requested differently using different prefixes with and without trailing slash.

Using the `location /prefix/ { ... }` style has the following advantages:

- you'd never face the situation when the other route starting with the same prefix, e.g. `/prefixed` will be handled with the wrong location;
- all the assets referred using relative links will get correct `/prefix/` automatically when being requested;
- you can easily strip the `/prefix` from the proxied URI using the autoreplace `proxy_pass` directive feature when it it's declaration includes an URI part (the trailing slash here is an URI part):

  ```
  location /prefix/ {
      proxy_pass http://upstream/;
  }
  ```

  This behavior is described in the `proxy_pass` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

  > If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
  >
  > ```
  > location /name/ {
  >     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
  > }
  > ```
- The redirection from `/prefix` to `/prefix/` will be automatically issued by nginx itself in most cases; this behavior is described in the `location` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

  > If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, `scgi_pass`, `memcached_pass`, or `grpc_pass`, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended.

Unfortunately I don't know for sure how you should change your [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware function. An English documentation page [suggests](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) the following approach:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Russian translation of the aforementioned documentation page suggests a different one:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Or maybe you should define your URI prefix directly:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('/strapiClient/public'));
```

Nevertheless, I hope this answers some of your questions, at least partially, and gives you some starting point of where to start debugging your app and the express static module behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the brower context, your tip fix the inconsistencies on the URL - now all brosers shows the correct URL.

The static issue remains and I'm trying to figure out how to debug, since Nodemon shows nothing in it's console.

Comment: When you'd manage to fix your `express.static` middleware, please post the solution here too, it could be helpful to other people trying to serve that kind of web applications under an URI prefix.

Comment: `console.log('Root directory: ' + __dirname);` gave me _/home/webmaster/apps/strapiClient_

Comment: `console.log(app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public'))));` gave me a lot of things but I pay attention on response's last part: _mountpath: '/',_ Now I'm gonna try to understand why not _mountpath: '/strapiClient',_