# Unexplainable Node JS "Cannot POST/GET" errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have an NodeJS SPA with a strange behaviour and for that I MUST to use "brute force" to make `express.static()` works:

```
app.use('*/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/images')));
```

Now I'm facing a problem in another URL that I must to make a POST req:

[image: (GoogleChrome imagem)]

On the red dot:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**

That´s the server.js file:

```
// Load Node modules
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var falaUser = require('./routes/falaUser');

(...)

// Render static files
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('*/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/images')));
app.use('*/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/js')));
app.use('*/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/css')));
app.use('*/slick-1.8.1', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/slick-1.8.1')));
app.use('*/falauser', falaUser);


(...)

// Root Route
app.get('/strapiClient/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});
```

That´s the falaUser.js route file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
var config = require("config");

router.post('/strapiClient', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  axios
    .post(config.get("botUrl"),
      req.body
    )
    .then((dataBot) => {
      console.log(dataBot.data.responses);
      res.json({
        "responses": dataBot.data.responses
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json(error);
    })

});
```

The output from `.catch(error)` is
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

To be sure that the issue is due routing, I tested with a GET requisition, putting this code on falaUser.js:

```
router.get('/strapiClient', function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    fruta: 'lichia'
  });
});
```

And I had a "Cannot GET /strapiClient/falauser" error...

Any clue on how to dig into it?

[The page is here](https://botboutique.com.br/strapiClient), if want to take a look: go to the botton of the page and type "opa" in the chatbot area.

Comment: The combination of `app.use('/falauser', falaUser);` and `router.post('/strapiClient', ...)` listens for `POST /falauser/strapiClient`, not for `POST /strapiClient/falauser`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, first I tried in server.js only, modifying app.use to `app.use('*/falauser', falaUser);` and `app.use('strapiClient/falauser', falaUser);` booth with no results. Keep it and change router.GET to `'strapiClient/falauser'` and `'*/falauser'` with no results

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, I edited the question to add this:

The output from `.catch(error)` is
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Comment: You server still contains no route that would match `POST /strapiClient/falauser`. Have you updated the question to reflect your code changes?

Comment: Yes, I edited: now I'm using `app.use('*/falauser', falaUser);` to have sintax consistency in server.js, and rip off useless code. But the question as I posted remains :-(

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use("/path1", router.post("/path2", ...))
```

matches only `POST /path1/path2` requests. In your case, `path2 = "strapiClient"`, hence the POST URL must end with `/strapiClient`, and `POST /strapiClient/falauser` is not matched.

See the following sentence in the [`Router` documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use):

> The “mount” path is stripped and is not visible to the middleware function. The main effect of this feature is that a mounted middleware function may operate without code changes regardless of its “prefix” pathname.

Comment: Take off  the router.post(...) from routes/falaUser.js and inserted into app.use in server.js `app.use("/falauser", router.post('/strapiClient', function (req, res, next) {...}))` with no results.